# I login and i'm immediately logged out. Why?

Tags: python, authentication, flask, flask-login

I'm trying to understand why after i login, as soon as i redirect to another page different from the login one i'm logged out. I don't think the bug is inside the login view,i'm pretty sure that this is linked to something subtler. The following code is anyway related to the login management.

```
@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
form = LoginForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = load_user(form.username.data)
        if user is not None and user.verify_password(form.password.data):
            if form.remember_me.data == True:
                login_user(user, remember=True)
            else:
                login_user(user)
            flash('Logged in successfully.')
            next = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next or url_for('home'))
        else:
            flash('Wrong username and/or password')

    form.username.data = request.args.get('username')
    return render_template('login.html', form=form, title='Login')

@lm.user_loader
def load_user(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username)
    if user.count()!=0 :
        return user.first()
    else:
        return None

@app.route("/logout")
@login_required
def logout():
    logout_user()
    flash('Logged out!')
    return to_index()
```

I don't know which other part of the code can be useful to post since i'm pretty confused about the origin of the problem itself.

Comment: you should be careful about indentation. your def logout(), looks like it will execute anytime u load_user()

Comment: your code looks correct, make sure your indentation is correct as mentioned by @Busturdust

Comment: yeah you're right. Anyway, i made that error when posting the code, so that's not (unfortunately) the reason of my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `user_loader` function takes an id, not a name.  You're comparing the id value to the username column and getting no results.  Use the `get` method to query for a `User` by primary key (id), or return None if no user with that id exists.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def user_loader(id):
    return User.query.get(id)
```